# Integration of $\int\log(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}) \, dx$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Integration of

$$\int\log\left(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\right) \, dx$$

Please help to go through this problem as i have started with putting $x$= $cos2y$.

Comment: What **precisely** is your problem?

Comment: write the integrand as $1\cdot \log(\sqrt{1 - x} + \sqrt{1 + x})$ and use integration by parts (integrating the factor $1$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is shorter to integrate by parts, setting $ u = \ln\bigl(\sqrt{1-x} + \sqrt{1 + x}\bigr) $, hence:
\begin{align*}
  \mathrm d\mkern1.5mu u & = \frac{\frac12\Bigl(\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x}} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}}\Bigr)}{\sqrt{1-x} + \sqrt{1 + x}}\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x= \frac12\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1 + x}}{\sqrt{(1-x²)}\Bigl(\sqrt{1-x} + \sqrt{1 + x}\Bigr)}\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x\\& = -\frac{1}{4x}\frac{\bigl(\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{1 + x}\bigr)² }{\sqrt{(1-x²)}}\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x =\frac{1}{2x}\frac{\sqrt{1-x²}-1}{\sqrt{1-x²}}\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x
\end{align*}
Setting $I=\displaystyle\int\log(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x})\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x$, you get:
\begin{align*}
I & =x\ln\bigl(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\bigr)-\frac{1}{2}\int\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x²}}\Bigr)\,\mathrm d\mkern1.5mu x\\
 & = x \ln\bigl(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x}\bigr)+\frac12(\arcsin x-x). 
\end{align*}

Comment: I think your arcsin part has the wrong sign. It should be $+\frac{1}{2}\arcsin x$, shouldn't it? The error comes from the second line of $du$.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for checking the computations! I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the integral
\begin{align}
I = \int\log(\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1+x})dx 
\end{align}
It is seen that
\begin{align}
I &= \int \ln\left[ \sqrt{1 -x} \, \left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \right) \right] dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int \ln(1-x) \, dx + \int \ln\left(1 + \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \right) dx
\end{align}
Now make the substitution 
\begin{align}
u^{2} = \frac{1+x}{1-x}
\end{align}
to obtain
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2} [ (x-1) \ln(1-x) - x] + \int \frac{4 \ln(1+u) \, u \, du}{(1+u^{2})^{2}}.
\end{align}
Integration by parts leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2} [ (x-1) \ln(1-x) - x] + \frac{2 \ln(1+u)}{1+u^{2}} - \int \frac{du}{(1+u)(1+u^{2})} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} [ (x-1) \ln(1-x) - x] + \frac{2 \ln(1+u)}{1+u^{2}} + \frac{1}{4} \ln(1 + u^{2}) - \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+u) - \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}(u).
\end{align}
Now reverse substitution yields
\begin{align}
I &= \frac{1}{2} [ (x-1) \ln(1-x) - x] + \left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right) \ln\left(1+ \sqrt{\frac{1 + x}{1-x}} \right) + \frac{1}{4} \ln\left(\frac{2}{1-x} \right) 
- \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{1 + x}{1-x}} \right) \\
&= \frac{\ln(2)}{4} - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \left( x - \frac{3}{2}\right) \ln(1-x) + \left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right) \ln\left(1+ \sqrt{\frac{1 + x}{1-x}} \right) - \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{1 + x}{1-x}} \right)
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $x = \sin (2u)$. Can you complete square and take square root? and don't forget the integration by part.

Comment: finally i got $$\int 2cos2u* log(2sinu)du$$